# Azure Data Factory - dynamically deal with trailing column delimiters

Tags: azure-data-factory, derived-column

I've got a blob container of tab delimited files that I'm trying to automate to import to am azure SQL database. One table per file
Every source file has a different schema.

I've got a for each loop to loop through the files in the blob container, then the copy data task uses the file metadata to pass parameters into a generic source dataset and automatically create tables in the SQL database sink.

The process is fine - HOWEVER - the source files all have a trailing tab - which the datafactory is interpreting as a column without a name - so I get this error:

> ErrorCode=DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The name of column index 36 is empty. Make sure column name is properly specified in the header row.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

I think this partially answers my question: [ADF Copy with trailing column delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871486/azure-adf-copy-activity-with-trailing-column-delimiter)

But how do I get it to work **dynamically?** The solution above manually specifies the 'valid' columns in the dataset to exclude the empty ones, but my 'valid' columns will change each time through the for each loop for each different source file, so I can't hardcode.

Cheers

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly then I had a similar issue.  I wanted my pipeline to be dynamic so it could ingest flat files with differing column mapping.  I generate the json for the column mapping and pass it to the pipeline as a parameter.

You can also parameterise the row delimiter in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve the desired output using copy activity.

Instead use dataflow for this. In the source, dataflow will give the projection like below.

[image]

For extra trailing tab(`\t`), it will give the name like above.

So, filter that extra column using select transformation.

```
instr(name,'_c')==0
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Add the SQL table as sink and it will copy the desired columns to the target table. Use dataset parameters for the source and sink to do this process dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like exactly what I'm after. 
When you say add the SQL table as a sink, does this mean that this effectively replaces the copy data activity?
Because I'm auto-creating the database tables in the copy data in my pipeline, will I need to have pre-created them to use them as sinks in the dataflow?

Comment: Never mind - found the settings that control the sink behaviour.

Comment: @SPT - intend to. Still trying to confirm it works though as other bits of the pipeline keep throwing errors, including not being able to get the pipeline to run in debug.
Think I've resolved most of them & will update asap.

Comment: @yonabout, There is no need to pre-create the tables before the dataflow. Dataflow will create the tables automatically. Just use dataset parameters to create the target tables dynamically. And Yes this will replace the copy activity.

Comment: This worked really well. I'm getting errors elsewhere, but this deals perfectly with the issue I was having.