# Azure data factory - spark jobs for dataflows taking forever

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a pipeline that reads files in blob storage, loops through them and loads the contents to Azure SQL tables. Datasets are parameterised as the files in the source directory may change, and the tables they write to change correspondingly.

I do the source -> sink in a dataflow activity because sometimes the (delimited) files have empty trailing columns at the end of a file if an additional delimiter has been left on which causes errors in source -> sink transforms. So I use a select transformation (because : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274421/azure-data-factory-dynamically-deal-with-trailing-column-delimiters))

When I debug the flow it takes **hours** to run.

I've got about 90 files to process - every dataflow run typically looks like this:

[image]

So the cluster startup is anything from 18 -> 25 minutes, but the actual components (source -> select transform -> sink) process pretty rapidly:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is it this slow because its in debug rather than being a published pipeline?
2. say the spark pool has 8 cores, does that mean that 8 dataflows are running concurrently, then the cluster stops and restarts for the next dataflow?
3. If 2 is yes, what's the best way of improving performance? can I:
   a) just pick a bigger spark pool so there's more concurrent jobs?
   b) start a pool before I start looping through dataflows and have the dataflows use free cores
   in that pool?

Any advice / insight gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it really takes some time when you are using Data Flow, but have you tried enabling Time to live option of your IR? Enabling this option helps lessen data flow activity time.

[image]

Comment: I'm just running it in debug - so using the AutoresolveIntegrationRuntime - I have to select a "debug time to live" to use it.

Would it be better to create a new Azure IR and use that instead?

Comment: Debug time to live is actually different with Time to live option in the IR. And yes, it would be better to create another IR since the default one won’t let you enable the TTL option.

Comment: That sorted it - thanks. 
Even with a small compute size it's massively quicker